# Shared preferences, where do they go?

Tags: android, preferences, shared

I know how shared preferences work but I just dont know where to insert the code in the code below to save the users data.I have a login , background task that does all the work and registration .I want the app to open to a splash page when user logged in.Cant figure it out from other answers

Login.java

```
Button bttnLogin;
EditText loginEmail, loginPassword;
TextView regLink;
AlertDialog.Builder alert;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);

    loginEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
    loginPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);

    regLink = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.regLink);
    regLink.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            startActivity(new Intent(Login.this, Register.class));

        }
    });


    bttnLogin = (Button) findViewById(R.id.bttnLogin);
    bttnLogin.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
    {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v)
        {
            if (loginEmail.getText().toString().equals("") || loginPassword.getText().toString().equals(""))
            {
                alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(Login.this);
                alert.setTitle("Login Failed");
                alert.setMessage("Try again");
                alert.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
                {

                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
                    {

                        dialog.dismiss();
                    }

                });

                AlertDialog alertDialog = alert.create();
                alertDialog.show();
            } else  //if user provides proper data
            {
                BackgroundTask backgroundTask = new BackgroundTask(Login.this);
                backgroundTask.execute("login", loginEmail.getText().toString(), loginPassword.getText().toString());
            }

        }


    });
```

Register.java

```
        private Button regButton;
        public EditText regName;
        public EditText regEmail;
        public EditText regPassword;
        public EditText conPassword;
        private AlertDialog.Builder alert;



@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_register);

    regName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.name);
    regEmail = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.email);
    regPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.password);
    conPassword = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.conPassword);
    regButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.regButton);
    regButton.setOnClickListener(this);
}


@Override
public void onClick(View v)
{

    if (regName.getText().toString().equals("") || regEmail.getText().toString().equals("") ||  regPassword.getText().toString().equals("") || conPassword.getText().toString().equals(""))
    {
        alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(Register.this);
        alert.setTitle("Something not quite right");
        alert.setMessage("Please fill in all the fields");
        alert.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
            {

                dialog.dismiss();
            }

        });

        AlertDialog alertDialog = alert.create();
        alertDialog.show();

    } else if (!(regPassword.getText().toString().equals(conPassword.getText().toString())))
    {

        alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(Register.this);
        alert.setTitle("Passwords do not match");
        alert.setMessage("Try Again");
        alert.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
            {

                dialog.dismiss();

                conPassword.setText("");
                regPassword.setText("");
            }

        });

        AlertDialog alertDialog = alert.create();
        alertDialog.show();


    }
    else //if user provides proper data
    {
        BackgroundTask backgroundTask = new BackgroundTask(Register.this);
        backgroundTask.execute("register", regName.getText().toString(), regEmail.getText().toString()
                , regPassword.getText().toString(), conPassword.getText().toString());
    }
```

BackgroundTask.java

```
 public class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>
{

private Context context;
private Activity activity;
private String reg_url = "http://blaah.com/register.php";
private String login_url = "http://blaah.com/login.php";
private AlertDialog.Builder builder;
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;


public BackgroundTask(Context context)
{

    this.context = context;
    activity = (Activity) context;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute()
{
    builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    progressDialog.setTitle("Please wait");
    progressDialog.setMessage("Connecting to Server...");
    progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    progressDialog.show();
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params)
{

    String method = params[0];

    if (method.equals("register"))
    {

        try
        {
            URL url = new URL(reg_url);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
            OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
            String name = params[1];
            String email = params[2];
            String username = params[3];
            String password = params[4];
            String data = URLEncoder.encode("name", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(name, "UTF-8") + "&" +
                    URLEncoder.encode("email", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(email, "UTF-8") + "&" +
                    URLEncoder.encode("password", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(password, "UTF-8");
            bufferedWriter.write(data);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            outputStream.close();
            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            String line = "";
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
            {

                stringBuilder.append(line).append("\n");

            }


            httpURLConnection.disconnect();
            Thread.sleep(8000);
            return stringBuilder.toString().trim();

        } catch (MalformedURLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    else if (method.equals("login"))
    {
        try
        {
            URL url = new URL(login_url);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
            OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));


            String username,password;

            username = params[1];
            password = params [2];
            String data = URLEncoder.encode("email", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(username, "UTF-8") + "&" +
                    URLEncoder.encode("password", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(password, "UTF-8");
            bufferedWriter.write(data);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            outputStream.close();

            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            String line = "";
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
            {

                stringBuilder.append(line + "\n");

            }


            httpURLConnection.disconnect();
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            return stringBuilder.toString().trim();


        } catch (MalformedURLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ProtocolException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values)
{
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String json)
{
   try
   {

       progressDialog.dismiss();


       Log.v("JSON", json);
       JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
       JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("server_response");
       JSONObject jsonobject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
       String code = jsonobject.getString("code");
       String message = jsonobject.getString("message");



       if(code.equals("reg_true"))
       {
           showDialog("Sucessful registration.Thank you.Enjoy_AS!", message, code);
       }

       else if (code.equals("reg_false"))
       {
           showDialog("User Already exists", message, code);
       }

       else if (code.equals("login_true"))
       {
           Toast.makeText(context, "You are logged in", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           Intent intent = new Intent(activity, SplashScreen.class);
           activity.startActivity(intent);


       } else if (code.equals("login_false"))
       {
           showDialog("Login Error", message, code);
       }


   } catch (JSONException e){
       e.printStackTrace();
   }


}

public void  showDialog(String title,String message,String code)
{

    builder.setTitle(title);
    if (code.equals("reg_true") || code.equals("reg_false"))
    {
        builder.setMessage(message);//message form server
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()

        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
            {
                dialog.dismiss();
                activity.finish();

            }
        });


    }

    else if (code.equals("login_false"))
    {


        builder.setMessage(message);
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
            {
                EditText loginEmail, loginPassword;
                loginEmail = (EditText) activity.findViewById(R.id.email);
                loginPassword = (EditText) activity.findViewById(R.id.password);
                loginEmail.setText("");
                loginPassword.setText("");
                dialog.dismiss();

            }


        });


    }
    AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
}

}
```

splash screen I want app to open to

```
 final String TAG = this.getClass().getName();
private static int SPLASH_TIME_OUT = 4000;
private TextView saying;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    //this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    supportRequestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
                         WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash_screen);

    saying = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.saying);
    Typeface mainHead =  Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), "fonts/emporo.TTF");
    saying.setTypeface(mainHead);
    //Set text custom font for subhead text


    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable()
    {


        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            // This method will be executed once the timer is over
            // Start your app main activity
            Intent i = new Intent(SplashScreen.this, HomeScreen.class);
            startActivity(i);

            // close this activity
            finish();
        }
    }, SPLASH_TIME_OUT);

}
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is what I use in my every Android app for `SharedPreferences`

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;

/**
 * Created by Jimit Patel on 30/07/15.
 */
public class Prefs {

    private static final String TAG = Prefs.class.getSimpleName();

    private static final String MY_APP_PREFS = "my_app";

    /**
     * <p>Provides Shared Preference object</p>
     * @param context
     * @return
     */
    private static SharedPreferences getPrefs(Context context) {
        return context.getSharedPreferences(MY_APP_PREFS, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    }

    /**
     * <p>Saves a string value for a given key in Shared Preference</p>
     * @param context
     * @param key
     * @param value
     */
    public static void setString(Context context, String key, String value) {
        getPrefs(context).edit().putString(key, value).apply();
    }

    /**
     * <p>Saves integer value for a given key in Shared Preference</p>
     * @param context
     * @param key
     * @param value
     */
    public static void setInt(Context context, String key, int value) {
        getPrefs(context).edit().putInt(key, value).apply();
    }

    /**
     * <p>Saves float value for a given key in Shared Preference</p>
     * @param context
     * @param key
     * @param value
     */
    public static void setFloat(Context context, String key, float value) {
        getPrefs(context).edit().putFloat(key, value).apply();
    }

    /**
     * <p>Saves long value for a given key in Shared Preference</p>
     * @param context
     * @param key
     * @param value
     */
    public static void setLong(Context context, String key, long value) {
        getPrefs(context).edit().putLong(key, value).apply();
    }

    /**
     * <p>Saves boolean value for a given key in Shared Preference</p>
     * @param context
     * @param key
     * @param value
     */
    public static void setBoolean(Context context, String key, boolean value) {
        getPrefs(context).edit().putBoolean(key, value).apply();
    }

    /**
     * Provides string from the Shared Preferences
     * @param context
     * @param key
     * @param defaultValue
     * @return
     */
    public static String getString(Context context, String key, String defaultValue) {
        return getPrefs(context).getString(key, defaultValue);
    }

    /**
     * Provides int from Shared Preferences
     * @param context
     * @param key
     * @param defaultValue
     * @return
     */
    public static int getInt(Context context, String key, int defaultValue) {
        return getPrefs(context).getInt(key, defaultValue);
    }

    /**
     * Provides boolean from Shared Preferences
     * @param context
     * @param key
     * @param defaultValue
     * @return
     */
    public static boolean getBoolean(Context context, String key, boolean defaultValue) {
        return getPrefs(context).getBoolean(key, defaultValue);
    }

    /**
     * Provides float value from Shared Preferences
     * @param context
     * @param key
     * @param defaultValue
     * @return
     */
    public static float getFloat(Context context, String key, float defaultValue) {
        return getPrefs(context).getFloat(key, defaultValue);
    }

    /**
     * Provides long value from Shared Preferences
     * @param context
     * @param key
     * @param defaultValue
     * @return
     */
    public static long getLong(Context context, String key, long defaultValue) {
        return getPrefs(context).getLong(key, defaultValue);
    }

    public static void clearPrefs(Context context) {
        getPrefs(context).edit().clear().commit();
    }
}
```

to use it you can just use those functions from it

Answer (score 0):

Once you received the login success from the server, implement the below code

```
SharedPreferences sharedpreferences = getSharedPreferences(MyPREFERENCES, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);    
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedpreferences.edit();
editor.putString("hasLoggedIn", true);
editor.commit();
```

And wherever you want to check whether the user is logged in not, you can check by using the following code.

```
boolean hasLoggedIn = sharedpreferences.getBoolean("hasLoggedIn", false);
```

If the **hasLogged** boolean value is true then the user had logged in.

Answer (score 0):

Just create a class called SessionManagement.java and paste the below code

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import java.util.HashMap;

/**
* Created by naveen.tp on 21/4/2016.
*/
public class SessionManagement {

SharedPreferences sharedPreferences;
SharedPreferences.Editor editor;
Context context;

int PRIVATE_MODE = 0;

private static final String PREF_NAME = "YourPreferences";

private static final String IS_LOGIN = "isLogedIn";

//Constructor
public SessionManagement(Context context) {

    this.context = context;
    sharedPreferences = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_NAME, PRIVATE_MODE);
    editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
}


//Create Login Session
public void createLoginSession(boolean flag)
{
    editor.putBoolean(IS_LOGIN, flag);
    editor.commit();
}

//check for isLogin returns True/false
public boolean isLoggedIn()
{
    return sharedPreferences.getBoolean(IS_LOGIN, false);
}

}
```

In your code BackgroundTask.java onPostExcecute method

**EDITED**

```
else if(code.equals("login_true"))
{
 SessionManagement session = new SessionManagement(context);
 session.createLoginSession(true);
 Toast.makeText(context, "You are logged in", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
 Intent intent = new Intent(activity, SplashScreen.class);
 activity.startActivity(intent);
}
```

You can also check for Login status next time in your splash screen just by calling

**EDITED**

```
SessionManagement session = new SessionManagement(this); 
boolean isLogin = session.isLoggedIn();
if(isLogin)
{
  //Already logged in
}
else
{
  //Not logged in
}
```

Hope that helps you!

Comment: Tried this but didnt work , gives me error on boolean isLogin = session.isLoggedIn();.No doubt im doing something wrong.

Comment: Hey , sorry been busy , error comes when running app , java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean com.example.xxxxxxxx.project.userdata.SessionManagement.isLoggedIn()' on a null object reference.I have to create a  variable for session in session.isLoggedIn(); .I have put the boolean isLogin in the onCreate method of splashscreen But it just throws the error .

Comment: You just need to call 'Sessionmanagement session = SessionManagement(this);' in onCreate before calling the method 'session.isLoggedIn()'. That works fine.

Comment: Ok done that still not working app crashing .This is the error"Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.content.SharedPreferences android.content.Context.getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String, int)' on a null object refere" .The only dofference is android studio is making me put new before Session managment, SessionManagement session = new SessionManagement(context); .

Comment: See my edited answer. It is tested and working at my end.

Comment: Ok its obviously me so because  I cant get it to work.I enter user details and when i hit login button the app hangs .It stays on the login screen.The toast message shows but it doesnt go to the splashscreen. There are no errors ,  the log shows activity_launch request  ,which just keeps rolling over and over .

Answer (score 0):

You Created Share Preferenced Method And save it

You Can use This Code ...helpful For you

savaLoginValue(mobileno, password, userTypeId, clientid);

```js
private void savaLoginValue(String mobileno, String password) 
{
        SharedPreferences login = getSharedPreferences("Preferance", MODE_PRIVATE);
        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = login.edit();
        editor.putString("SPMobileno", mobileno);
        editor.putString("SPPass", password);
        editor.commit();
}
```

BackgoundTask.Class

```js
public class BackgroundTask extends AsyncTask<String,Void,String>
{

private Context context;
private Activity activity;
private String reg_url = "http://blaah.com/register.php";
private String login_url = "http://blaah.com/login.php";
private AlertDialog.Builder builder;
private ProgressDialog progressDialog;


public BackgroundTask(Context context)
{

    this.context = context;
    activity = (Activity) context;
}

@Override
protected void onPreExecute()
{
    builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(activity);
    progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);
    progressDialog.setTitle("Please wait");
    progressDialog.setMessage("Connecting to Server...");
    progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
    progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
    progressDialog.show();
}

@Override
protected String doInBackground(String... params)
{

    String method = params[0];

    if (method.equals("register"))
    {

        try
        {
            URL url = new URL(reg_url);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
            OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));
            String name = params[1];
            String email = params[2];
            String username = params[3];
            String password = params[4];
            String data = URLEncoder.encode("name", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(name, "UTF-8") + "&" +
                    URLEncoder.encode("email", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(email, "UTF-8") + "&" +
                    URLEncoder.encode("password", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(password, "UTF-8");
            bufferedWriter.write(data);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            outputStream.close();
            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            String line = "";
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
            {

                stringBuilder.append(line).append("\n");

            }


            httpURLConnection.disconnect();
            Thread.sleep(8000);
            return stringBuilder.toString().trim();

        } catch (MalformedURLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }
    else if (method.equals("login"))
    {
        try
        {
            URL url = new URL(login_url);
            HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            httpURLConnection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            httpURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
            httpURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
            OutputStream outputStream = httpURLConnection.getOutputStream();
            BufferedWriter bufferedWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(outputStream, "UTF-8"));


            String username,password;

            username = params[1];
            password = params [2];
            String data = URLEncoder.encode("email", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(username, "UTF-8") + "&" +
                    URLEncoder.encode("password", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(password, "UTF-8");
            bufferedWriter.write(data);
            bufferedWriter.flush();
            bufferedWriter.close();
            outputStream.close();

            InputStream inputStream = httpURLConnection.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(inputStream));
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            String line = "";
            while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
            {

                stringBuilder.append(line + "\n");

            }


            httpURLConnection.disconnect();
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            return stringBuilder.toString().trim();


        } catch (MalformedURLException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (ProtocolException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    return null;
}

@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values)
{
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
}

@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String json)
{
   try
   {

       progressDialog.dismiss();


       Log.v("JSON", json);
       JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
       JSONArray jsonArray = jsonObject.getJSONArray("server_response");
       JSONObject jsonobject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
       String code = jsonobject.getString("code");
       String message = jsonobject.getString("message");



       if(code.equals("reg_true"))
       {
           showDialog("Sucessful registration.Thank you.Enjoy_AS!", message, code);
       }

       else if (code.equals("reg_false"))
       {
           showDialog("User Already exists", message, code);
       }

       else if (code.equals("login_true"))
       {
         
         // Please You Can Take The Username & Password And Save It For Shared Preference Then Share Preference File Any where To Use It.. 
           Toast.makeText(context, "You are logged in", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           Intent intent = new Intent(activity, SplashScreen.class);
           activity.startActivity(intent);


       } else if (code.equals("login_false"))
       {
           showDialog("Login Error", message, code);
       }


   } catch (JSONException e){
       e.printStackTrace();
   }


}

public void  showDialog(String title,String message,String code)
{

    builder.setTitle(title);
    if (code.equals("reg_true") || code.equals("reg_false"))
    {
        builder.setMessage(message);//message form server
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()

        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
            {
                dialog.dismiss();
                activity.finish();

            }
        });


    }

    else if (code.equals("login_false"))
    {


        builder.setMessage(message);
        builder.setPositiveButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)
            {
                EditText loginEmail, loginPassword;
                loginEmail = (EditText) activity.findViewById(R.id.email);
                loginPassword = (EditText) activity.findViewById(R.id.password);
                loginEmail.setText("");
                loginPassword.setText("");
                dialog.dismiss();

            }


        });


    }
    AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
    alertDialog.show();
}

}
```