# Android, login using Rest API

Tags: android

I have an android app with a login that sends login information over https to a java rest api that verifies the login credentials and then sends back a response stating whether the login was successful. My question is simple, what should I do to make sure the user doesn't have to login in again when they restart the app?

Comment: You can make your API provide a Auth key that you can use to authenticate user for future API requests. you can set the validity of this Auth token as well. For more information read about JSON web token.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are many ways to deal with one time login, it depends a lot on how the architecture is implemented on server side to make it work. Usually Login API are `closely coupled` for security reason. let me example what I mean by `closely coupled`.

As you want to `Login` in to `Mobile App` work once and the next time user opens the `Mobile app` you don't want to prompt user with `SignIn` screen again. and surely you don't want to save the confidential information like `Username` and `Password` on Mobile app as persistent data, as it can be fetched easily from android device. so what you do.

Lets assume you pass login credentials with a `deviceID` unique to the `Android Device`. Something like shown below. following is the `JSON` data sent to the `LoginAPI`

```
{
    "username": "example@example.com",
    "password": "it's not a secret",
    "deviceId": "123456789"
}
```

Now as you don't want to save the `Login` credentials, server will generate a random alpha numeric `String` pass it to you in response every time you login to the Mobile App.

```
{
    "Success": true,
    "SuccessMessage": "credentials are correct, really!",
    "ErrorMessage": null,
    "Date": "dd/mm/yyyy",
    "token": "1eghe4qha23aehraeh456789" // now this is a nasty String
}
```

you may now save the `date` and the `token` in Mobile App as persistent data.
So next time your user opens the app you may let user bypass the `SignIn` screen, and in background you can check if users token id is correct by sending that to the server, something like this. you may choose [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html) or create a [file](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html) and save it there

```
{
    "API_TYPE": "login",
    "deviceId": "123456789",
    "token": "1eghe4qha23aehraeh456789"
}
```

Server may check this token id against the `deviceID` to check if this was the correct token for the device and respond.

You may ask why are we checking the `token` again as this was sent by the server in first place stating the credentials were correct. I agree you do have a point, lets say it is a fail safe condition, if the user changes the password from the website or something which causes to change the token on server for that user to change, if the server denies the token provided by you just ask the user to login again.

This will make sure that a user is logged in to only one `Android Device` at any given point of time.

Comment: Thanks for your help, this seems to be the best approach I've seen. I have one question about this though, isn't it bad practice to store a token on a device for too long? Would you recommend the following approach everytime the user goes back to the app after they have signed in for the first time:

1. The user opens the app, the token and device id stored in shared preferences is sent to the server
2. The server verifies the device id and token id with the device id and token id stored on the server......

Comment: 3. The server then generates a new token and if step 2 was successful it sends a new token along with the success message
4. The token id is then updated in shared preferences with the new one received from the server.

Would that be overkill? Also, would you recommend doing the token check over ssl?

Comment: @BenC, You have my attention you actually pinpointed some of the loop holes in this approach. What you have suggested is defiantly can be done and so does the `SSL` option. Remember I have added a `Date` key which would be provided by server as response. This date can be used to check when was the last time the `SignIn` took place successfully and you can invalidate the token after 10, 20 or 30 days and ask user to `SignIn` again

Comment: Using the date would be a good idea as well, thanks for your help.

Comment: @BenC, You are welcome, It was a pleasure to talk to you.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the credentials after the first login.
So when the user restart app, you can automatically make the request auth.

You can chose the best option to storage the credentials using the doc: 
[Data-Storage](http://developer.android.com/intl/pt-br/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html)

This is simple, but maybe not the best way to do this.

Comment: If use a passwords in your auth, remember to encrypt before storage.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problme,and I got a Json data from the server like this

```
{"error":0,"message":"ok","token":"7c75015e92e40511911e34752ee456e1","execute_time":"0.2723"}
```

so I keep the `StuToken`in SharedPreferences,and when my app start,check the `StuToken` does it exist,like this

```
Map<String, String> loginInfo = InfoUtil.getLoginInfo(MainActivity.this);
    if (loginInfo != null) {
        if (loginInfo.get("StuToken") != null) {
            getStuInfo(loginInfo.get("StuToken"));
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "登录状态", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            initIntent(LoginActivity.class);
            this.finish();
        }
    } else {
        initIntent(LoginActivity.class);
        this.finish();
    }
}
```

hope that will works for you

Answer (score 0):

You can use shared preference to store the values of the user and to check whether the user is already logged in or not. You can follow this [Link.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36769312/1501864)

Answer (score 0):

Try out this code in your SplashScreen Activity.You can store a value in a sharedPrefence to check whether user is Logged in or not.

```
public class SplashActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final long TIME_OUT_MILI = 3000;
    private SharedPreferences mAppPreferences;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
        mAppPreferences = AppUtil.getAppPreferences(this);

        new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                if (mAppPreferences.getBoolean("is_Logged_in", false)) {

                    startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this, MainActivity.class));

                } else {

                    startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this, LoginActivity.class));

                }
                finish();
            }
        }, TIME_OUT_MILI);
    }


}
```

In Your LoginActivity's do this:

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
 private SharedPreferences mAppPreferences;
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_login);
          SharedPreferences.Editor editor = mAppPreferences.edit();
editor.putBoolean(Constants.SETTINGS_IS_LOGGED_IN, true);
                        editor.commit();
}
}
```